# jquery get previous ID

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

Is it possible with jQuery to get the previous ID of an element when inside the element after it?

Example:

```
<div class="dropdown-slider" style="z-index:5;" id="notrecon_dis">
   <span class="ddm" onclick="saveDD(this);" id="dd-cat 1">     
     <span class="label">
        cat 1
     </span>
   </span>
</div>
```

I am using the onclick to get the clicked id value (**which would be dd-cat 1 in the above example**) but i am unsure on how to get the previous id element (**which would be notrecon_dis**).

How could i do this using jQuery?

Comment: `id="dd-cat 1"` - You can't have a space in your ID's.

Answer (score 2):

```
var prevElem = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

You'll need to remove the space between dd-cat and 1.

Answer (score 1):

use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.ddm').on('click', function() {
    var prevId = $(this).closest('div.dropdown-slider').attr('id');
    alert(prevId);
});
```

OR

```
function saveDD(elem){
    var prevId = $(elem).closest('div.dropdown-slider').attr('id');
    alert(prevId);
};
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ruUkn/)**